# Find out time it took for a python script to complete execution

Tags: python, datetime, execution-time

I have the following code in a python script:

```
def fun(): 
  #Code here

fun()
```

I want to execute this script and also find out how much time it took to execute in minutes. How do I find out how much time it took for this script to execute ? An example would be really appreciated.

Comment: First hit on search for "python function timing": http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216610

Comment: You can also use [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile).
Gives you the option to time each function separately

Answer (score 317):

```
from datetime import datetime
startTime = datetime.now()

#do something

#Python 2: 
print datetime.now() - startTime 

#Python 3: 
print(datetime.now() - startTime)
```

Comment: New to Python, working in 3.6.1. FYI datetime no longer has a now attribute.

Comment: @WizzleWuzzle `datetime.now()` works if you do `from datetime import datetime`, not just `import datetime` (just confirmed on Python 3.6.4).

Comment: Same case in Python 3.8 it's just the library's absurdity module `datetime` has `datetime` class in it... I'm kinda surprised the `datetime` class doesn't have `datetime` attribute in it -_- .....

Comment: What is neat: `datetime`(class) has implemented `__str__` with an ISO format, so if you convert your datetime instance to `str()`ing or `print()` it, the format will be `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.mmmmmm`, it is an equivalent of calling `your_datetime.isoformat(sep=' ')` ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.__str__

Comment: I think `time.perf_counter()` is better than this, [added it as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786990/find-out-time-it-took-for-a-python-script-to-complete-execution/70213993#70213993). I am unsure, so I asked about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70233836/datetime-now-vs-time-perf-counter-which-one-to-use-to-find-execution-times).

Answer (score 155):

Do you execute the script from the command line on Linux or UNIX? In that case, you could just use

```
time ./script.py
```

Comment: `time -p ./script.py`

`-p` flag for pipeline

Comment: and what does pipeline helps us with?

Comment: time python myScript.py for windows
The out put will be
Execution time in seconds: 38.509970903396606

real    0m38.792s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.046s

Comment: @Joy I think you misread the `help time` => **"`-p print the timing summary in the portable Posix format`"** I think here `time [-p] pipeline` you've confused an option with argument :) pipeline is an *argument* (not an option) - **the pipeline itself**. "Execute PIPELINE and print a summary of the real time, user CPU time, and system CPU time spent executing PIPELINE when it terminates" so **it's pipeline by default**, `-p` doesn't have anything to do with it :)

Comment: + **PIPE(|)LINE RUNS IN PARALEL** (not serially as I and I think many others thought :) ) so e.g. `time sleep 5 | sleep 10` **will only measure 10 seconds**, since those sleeps actually run in paralel and the whole pipeline finishes in about 10s.

Comment: This timing result will include the loading of the Python interpreter, which will take 1s or so. In many cases, for instance for an image processing pipeline, where the Python interpreter is already running, you want to exclude that interpreter loading time. In an iPython shell that exclusion is provided because the iPython shell is already running and one can execute e.g. "%timeit %run my_script.py --parameters". Here we seek an alternative from bash or equivalent. I did not find that yet.

Answer (score 79):

```
import time
start = time.time()

fun()

# python 2
print 'It took', time.time()-start, 'seconds.'

# python 3
print('It took', time.time()-start, 'seconds.')
```

Comment: Last line should probably read `print('It took {0:0.1f} seconds'.format(time.time() - start))` in python 3.x.

Comment: @ChrisMueller I was working in python2.7. I'll leave the comment here though so people can see both versions.

Comment: `time.perf_counter()` is I believe better than `time.time()`. Added [such an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786990/find-out-time-it-took-for-a-python-script-to-complete-execution/70213993#70213993).

Answer (score 18):

What I usually do is use `clock()` or `time()` from the `time` library. `clock` measures interpreter time, while `time` measures system time. Additional caveats can be found in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html).

For example,

```
def fn():
    st = time()
    dostuff()
    print 'fn took %.2f seconds' % (time() - st)
```

Or alternatively, you can use `timeit`. I often use the `time` approach due to how fast I can bang it out, but if you're timing an isolate-able piece of code, `timeit` comes in handy.

From the [timeit docs](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html),

```
def test():
    "Stupid test function"
    L = []
    for i in range(100):
        L.append(i)

if __name__=='__main__':
    from timeit import Timer
    t = Timer("test()", "from __main__ import test")
    print t.timeit()
```

Then to convert to minutes, you can simply divide by 60. If you want the script runtime in an easily readable format, whether it's seconds or days, you can convert to a `timedelta` and `str` it:

```
runtime = time() - st
print 'runtime:', timedelta(seconds=runtime)
```

and that'll print out something of the form `[D day[s], ][H]H:MM:SS[.UUUUUU]`. You can check out the [timedelta docs](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).

And finally, if what you're actually after is profiling your code, Python makes available the [profile library](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html#module-pstats) as well.

Answer (score 18):

```
import sys
import timeit

start = timeit.default_timer()

#do some nice things...

stop = timeit.default_timer()
total_time = stop - start

# output running time in a nice format.
mins, secs = divmod(total_time, 60)
hours, mins = divmod(mins, 60)

sys.stdout.write("Total running time: %d:%d:%d.\n" % (hours, mins, secs))
```

Comment: the print out for 50 seconds is "0:0:50"

Answer (score 17):

```
import time 

startTime = time.time()
# Your code here !
print ('The script took {0} second !'.format(time.time() - startTime))
```

The previous code works for me with no problem !

Answer (score 12):

Use the timeit module. It's very easy. Run your example.py file so it is active in the Python Shell, you should now be able to call your function in the shell. Try it out to check it works

```
>>>fun(input)
output
```

Good, that works, now import timeit and set up a timer

```
>>>import timeit
>>>t = timeit.Timer('example.fun(input)','import example')
>>>
```

Now we have our timer set up we can see how long it takes

```
>>>t.timeit(number=1)
some number here
```

And there we go, it will tell you how many seconds (or less) it took to execute that function. If it's a simple function then you can increase it to t.timeit(number=1000) (or any number!) and then divide the answer by the number to get the average.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 10):

### Pure Python

Better yet is `time.perf_counter()`:

```
t0 = time.perf_counter()
fun()
t1 = time.perf_counter()
print(t1-t0)

# and if you really want your answer in minutes:
print(f"In minutes: {(t1-t0)/60}")
```

Recommended by [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qUeud6DvOWI) as well ([5:30](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qUeud6DvOWI&t=330s)).

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter):

> `time.`**`perf_counter()`**`→ float`
>
> Return the value (in fractional seconds) of a performance counter,
> i.e. a clock with the highest available resolution to measure a short
> duration. It does include time elapsed during sleep and is
> system-wide. The reference point of the returned value is undefined,
> so that only the difference between the results of two calls is valid.
>
> Use [`perf_counter_ns()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter_ns) to avoid the precision loss caused by the
> float type.
>
> *New in version 3.3.*
>
> *Changed in version 3.10:* On Windows, the function is now system-wide.

---

### Jupyter Notebook: `%timeit` & `%time`

If you are working in a Jupyter Notebook (such as [Google Colab](http://colab.research.google.com)), you can use IPython Magic Commands.

Example:

```
import time
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

def fun(): 
    time.sleep(0.1+np.random.rand()*0.05)
```

Then in a separate cell, **to time the function *multiple* times**:

```
%timeit fun()
```

Output:

```
10 loops, best of 5: 120 ms per loop
```

**To time the function only *once*:**

```
%time fun()
```

Output:

```
CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 621 µs, total: 621 µs
Wall time: 114 ms
```

You can find more about Magic Commands [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/jdwittenauer/ipython-notebooks/blob/master/notebooks/language/IPythonMagic.ipynb).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way I do this using functional programming - no global namespace pollution, proper inflection of plurals, only one decorator used, all with only four imports, compatible with versions of Python starting from 3.6 (if type hints are removed). I have this function in all my scripts:

```
import re
import time
from functools import wraps
from typing import Callable, ParamSpec, TypeVar

P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")


def time_function(func: Callable[P, R]) -> Callable[P, R]:
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        """Time scripts using a decorator - no global namespace pollution, proper
        inflection of plurals, only only one decorator call,
        all with only four imports."""
        starting_time = time.perf_counter()
        name = func.__name__
        name = "main function" if name == "main" else f'function "{name}"'

        print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime()) + f": Starting {name}...")

        result = func(*args, **kwargs)

        # Formatting with proper inflection of plurals, using regular expressions
        runtime = time.strftime(
            "%#H hours, %#M minutes and %#S seconds",
            time.gmtime(time.perf_counter() - starting_time),
        )

        for old, new in (
            (r"^0 hours, ", ""),
            (r"^1 hours", "1 hour"),
            (r"\b0 minutes and ", ""),
            (r"\b1 minutes", "1 minute"),
            (r"\b1 seconds", "1 second"),
            (r"(?: and|,) 0 seconds", ""),
            (r"^0 seconds", "less than a second"),
        ):
            runtime = re.sub(old, new, runtime)
        # Make the 0-second or 0-minute situation sound more natural
        if ("second" in runtime) != ("minute" in runtime):
            runtime = runtime.replace(", ", " and ")
        print(f"{name} took {runtime} to run.".capitalize())

        return result

    return wrapper
```

Sample input:

```
@time_function
def main() -> None:
    time.sleep(15)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
20:58:28: Starting script...
The script took 15 seconds to run.
```

Sample input:

```
@time_function
def main() -> None:
    time.sleep(61)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
22:47:29: Starting script...
The script took 1 minute and 1 second to run.
```

Answer (score 1):

use the time and datetime packages.

if anybody want to execute this script and also find out how much time it took to execute in minutes

```
import time
from time import strftime
from datetime import datetime 
from time import gmtime

def start_time_():    
    #import time
    start_time = time.time()
    return(start_time)

def end_time_():
    #import time
    end_time = time.time()
    return(end_time)

def Execution_time(start_time_,end_time_):
   #import time
   #from time import strftime
   #from datetime import datetime 
   #from time import gmtime
   return(strftime("%H:%M:%S",gmtime(int('{:.0f}'.format(float(str((end_time-start_time))))))))

start_time = start_time_()
# your code here #
[i for i in range(0,100000000)]
# your code here #
end_time = end_time_()
print("Execution_time is :", Execution_time(start_time,end_time))
```

The above code works for me. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows users.**

If you want to record the time for executing a complete Python file, use the simple code given below.

```
Measure-Command {python YourScript.py}
```

Answer (score -1):

Import timeit module and define the part of the script you want to time as function (e.g. main()).

```
    import timeit
    
    BF = timeit.timeit('BruteForce_MemoryEfficiency.main()', setup='import BruteForce_MemoryEfficiency', number=1)
    
    print(BF)
```

The function will be executed 1 time (number=1) and the time needed will be measured.

Comment: This is a duplicate of other answers and doesn't bring any more value than 3 other answers already recommending the timeit module