# Is there a way to know when a script has finished running on a terminal?

Tags: logging, time, terminal

I ran a python script overnight, and it was already done when I checked the code in the morning.

Is there a time log stored somewhere of when the python script finished executing? Or maybe a log of the subprocesses running on the system that would give me the time when the script finished running? Or a terminal history? Is there a way to do this, without having to include a time logger in the script itself?

I am running my code on an Ubuntu 18.04 PC.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Ubuntu automatically logs your script, but you can always use datetime with print, which is an easy way of knowing when it starts of finishes. Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786990/find-out-time-it-took-for-a-python-script-to-complete-execution)

Comment: Yes, I know that I can use Datetime. The question was if there was a way to do it without writing something in the script.

Comment: When calling the script, try using time nameOfScript.sh, it should give you the completion time of the whole script.

Comment: Yes I know that!
My question was related to logging after the process/script has finished running. How would you find out when the particular script ended? I've been looking at syslogs, but it doesn't seem to show it.
To be more clear, I want to know if there is a log file for all system processes, and if there is what file is it?

Comment: In that case, no there isn't one for scripts. You will need to manually setup timestamp, datetime etc. Sorry for the confusion!